# How to make selenium(Chrome) webdriver wait until there is no pending request in the network? (Using JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried to iterate in the performance log until there are response method containing "WillBeSent" (pending) status... but the performance log is being automatically cleared and the request with the pending status cannot be retrieved.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
              do{
                    allmethod="";
                    sleep(1000);
                    logs = driver.manage().logs().get("performance");
                    for (Iterator<LogEntry> it = logs.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        LogEntry entry = it.next();
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(entry.getMessage());
                        JSONObject message = json.getJSONObject("message");
                        String method = message.getString("method");
                        allmethod = allmethod + " " + method;
                        System.out.println(allmethod);
                    }
                }while(allmethod.contains("WillBeSent")==Boolean.TRUE);
```

Is there any other way i can capture the any pending request in the Network tab in Chrome Using selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will solve your problem, this method will check for all DOM elements to be in ready state.

private void waitUntilJSReady() {

```
try {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) this.driver)
        .executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");

    boolean jsReady = jsExec.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");

    if (!jsReady) {
        jsWait.until(jsLoad);
    }
} catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
}
```

}